# I want to redirect both images on another URLs. when I implement TouchableOpacity on both images.one image get invisible

Tags: react-native

I want to redirect both images on another URLs. when I implement TouchableOpacity on both images.one image get invisible.

```
<View style={styles.enterbox}> 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {name: 'originator'})}> 
        <Image source={images.originator} style={styles.originator} /> 
    </TouchableOpacity > 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {name: 'vendor'})}> 
        <Image source={images.vendor} style={styles.vendor} /> 
    </TouchableOpacity > 
</View>
```

Comment: Where is the second image? I only see 1 Image tag..

Comment: <View style={styles.enterbox}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {name: 'originator'})}>
      <Image source={images.originator} style={styles.originator} /> 
      </TouchableOpacity >
       
      
     
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login', {name: 'vendor'})}>
       <Image source={images.vendor} style={styles.vendor}  /> 
       </TouchableOpacity >
  </View>

Comment: This is my code..please review